# Read XML file into struct

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rust

I am trying to write a program that reads an XML file into a previously defined Rust struct.

Something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note name="title">
  <body name="main_body">
    <layer content_type="something" count="99">
      <data id="13">
        Datacontent
      </data>
    </layer>
  </body>
</note>
```

Into this:

```
struct Note {
    name: String,
    Body: Body 
}

struct Body {
    name: String,
    layers: Vec<Layer>,
}

struct Layer {
    content_type: String,
    count: u8,
    data: Vec<Data>,
}

struct Data {
    id: u8,
    // Datacontent?
}
```

I looked at [xml-rs](https://github.com/netvl/xml-rs) because it currently appears to be the most popular XML library. Being new to Rust, I have a hard time figuring out how to perform this task.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Rust has great support for automatically generating (de)serialization code. There's the legacy [`rustc-serialize`](https://crates.io/crates/rustc-serialize) which requires very little setup. Then there's the [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde) crate which is a completely new (de)serialization framework that allows many formats and detailed custom configurations, but requires a little more initial setup.

I'm going to describe how to use `serde` + `serde_xml_rs` to deserialize the XML to the Rust-structs.

## Add the crates to your `Cargo.toml`

We could either implement the deserialization code manually, or we can generate it automatically by using the `serde_derive` crate.

```
[dependencies]
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde = "1.0"
serde-xml-rs = "0.3.1"
```

## Add annotations to your structs

Serde needs to know about your structs. To aid it and not generate code for every single struct in your project, you need to annotate the structs you want. The `Debug` derivation is so we can easily print the structs with `println!` to inspect whether everything worked. The `Deserialize` bound is what notifies `serde` to generate code. If you want to treat the contents of an xml tag as text, you need to "rename" the field that should contain the text to `$value`. The naming of `$value` was done very arbitrarily in the creation of the `serde_xml_rs` crate, but can never collide with an actual field, because field names can't contain `$` signs.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_xml_rs;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Note {
    name: String,
    body: Body,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Body {
    name: String,
    #[serde(rename="layer")]
    layers: Vec<Layer>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Layer {
    content_type: String,
    count: u8,
    data: Vec<Data>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Data {
    id: u8,
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    content: String,
}
```

## Turn a String containing xml into an object

Now comes the easy part. You call `serde_xml::from_str` on your string and you get either an error or a value of type `Node`:

```
fn main() {
    let note: Note = serde_xml_rs::deserialize(r##"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note name="title">
  <body name="main_body">
    <layer content_type="something" count="99">
      <data id="13">
        Datacontent
      </data>
    </layer>
  </body>
</note>
    "##.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", note);
}
```

Comment: I had to add this to Cargo.toml, instead: 
serde-xml-rs = "0.2.1"

Comment: The explanatory text for parsing refers to `serde_xml::from_str` whereas the code uses `serde_xml_rs::deserialize`. (Has one been edited without the other?) The `deserialize` method was removed in `serde_xml_rs` 0.3, but you can parse bytes in the current version 0.4.0 with `from_reader` instead (because `&[u8]` implements `Read`). But what with the shifting API and its general eagerness to choke on normal XML stuff such as a Unicode BOM or DOCTYPE declaration at the start of the file, `serde_xml_rs` doesn't seem particularly fit for purpose yet. `serde_xml` is abandoned.