# Serialize a struct containing a vec

Tags: xml, serialization, rust

I have a structure containing a vec

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Config {
    customer : Vec<Customer>,
}
```

And I want to serialize it to XML. I tried to use

serde_xml_rs::to_string(&config)

But it returns an error. It seems that serde_xml_rs cannot serialize vec's.

Is there a good XML serializer crate ?

Comment: Maybe doing some manual impl instead of the derive, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41416913/865874)?

Comment: Please include a [mre], ideally with a link to the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/), and paste the complete error message in the question. In particular what is `Customer`?

Comment: Does `Customer` implement `Serialize`? Does it work if you try to convert a single `Customer` to XML instead of a `Vec<Customer>`?

Comment: @Jmb: I'd say that the OP has found a limitation in the current [serde-xml-rs implementation](https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs/blob/7cf7074f783990f7f6a2be9dfc9dd3ea8e666240/src/ser/mod.rs#L234).

Comment: Yes, Customer implements Serialize, and yes, the serialization works if I use a single Customer instead of a Vec<Customer>.

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure if this answers your question completely.
Take an example struct :

```
 use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

 #[derive(Serialize,Deserialize, Debug)]
     pub struct Restaurant {
        cuisine: String,
        borough: String,
        name: String,
        address: Address
    }
```

And using that deserializer you query a db and get an array of Restaurant

```
let mut list_data = ArrayVec::<[Restaurant;1024]>::new();
```

This data object can then be serialized (to json) with the following:

```
let ser_data =list.serialize(
       serde_json::value::Serializer
).unwrap();
```

I'm not sure which xml library to use, though